# modify setattr to mass-assign multiple attributes to different values

Tags: python

I was trying to make a class that can assign multiple attributes to different values at one go. So, I tried to modify the setattr to do this.

```
class hello():
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        if type(attr) == str:
            self.__dict__[attr] = value
        elif type(attr) == list:
            for item,val in zip(attr,value):
                self.__dict__[item] = val
        else:
            print "Error!!!"
```

so that my desired class would have the property:

```
>>> hola = hello()
>>> setattr(hola,["a","b"],[1,2])
>>> hola.a
1
>>> hola.b
2
```

But doing this returns

```
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'list'
```

It is true that I can define a special method inside the class for this job, like

```
def assigner(self, attrlist, valuelist):
    for item,value in zip(attrlist,valuelist):
        self.__dict__[item] = value
```

But wanted to know why it is not possible via setattr and most efficient way to do this job

Comment: `if type(attr) == str:` you shouldn't do this to check for types. Use `isinstance` instead: `if isinstance(attr, str):`. Also note: instead of setting the attributes one by one in the `__dict__` you could do: `self.__dict__.update(zip(attrlist, valuelist))`. This is more efficient then doing it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs on the `setattr` function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr):

> The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value.

The second argument **has** to be `str`.

The possible workaround is to define `__setitem__` instead of `__setattr__`

```
class hello():
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.__dict__.update(zip(k, v) if type(k) is tuple else [(k, v)])
```

This will allow you to assign values in `dict` style

```
In [2]: heya = hello()

In [3]: heya['a', 'b'] = [1, 2]

In [4]: heya.a
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: heya.b
Out[5]: 2
```

Still, nothing stops you from assigning them like this

```
In [15]: heya.a, heya.b = [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the `TypeError` states it pretty well: the name (second argument) must be a string, not a list.

> The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr